# Is there empty std::string defined somewhere?

Tags: c++, string

Is there empty `std::string` defined somewhere?

What I mean is following:

I can do:

```
// code #1
int process(const char *s = nullptr);
// later I can use:
process();
```

However, if I do:

```
// code #2
int process(const std::string &s = "");
// later I can use:
process(); // wait, an object is created...
```

It compiles and works, when I use the function, there is unneeded object creation.

Is there standard way to do following:

```
// code #3
const std::string EMPTY_STR;
int process(const std::string &s = EMPTY_STR);
// later I can use:
process(); // fine, no object is created...
```

This is not bottleneck, nor it is a premature optimization.

I believe C++ is not Java, so right way is not to create objects that you do not need.

Also I believe `code 3` looks much better than `code 2` and also it show the intention that string is empty (and probably will not be used), than `code 2`, where is not very clear why the string is `""`.

Comment: what makes you think this is how it works (and the compiler won't optimize away the temporary)? And even if this is the case, did you prove by measurement that this causes a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: **Why?** Honestly it sounds like premature optimization that's discouraged and shouldn't matter if you enable optimization.

Comment: _If_ this is an actual performance bottleneck you always have the option of providing an overload that takes zero arguments and one that take  a string.

Comment: I have code like first one, and migrating it to the second one. Could be premature, but it does seems right way to me not to create additional objects, also const std::string s = nullptr; does not work and const std::string &s = "" have different meaning I believe. Using EMPTY_STR will show my intentions much better than ""

Comment: I don't believe there's a predefined empty string, because the need doesn't arise. But if you really want one, nobody's stopping you from creating your own `static` somewhere.

Comment: @MarkRansom this is what I am going to do, but I found most of things I try to do are already done in STL...

Comment: @Nick If you want speed, don't. I bet accessing this static variable will be slower that what you have now (at least not faster)

Comment: @deviantfan you are correct too...

Comment: It's worth noticing that short string/zero length string optimization makes the creation of such a temporary virtually free (=no heap allocations are involved).

Comment: Are you sure the real question isn't, "How do I avoid having to have a string that indicates that there is no string?" -- I think you're asking for the string equivalent of `char *s = "";` when what you really want is the string equivalent `char *s = NULL;`, and so you're getting the wrong answers for your real question. Is the desired semantic really an empty string or some way to indicate that there is no string?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - no, I need to have the object (I know it is not 100% same as in char * version)

Comment: I think you should get rid of bad habbit have constants in all UPPERCASE. They are not preprocessor macro anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I am slightly surprised you need an OBJECT. It is going to be a const object anyway, so what does it give you which simple const char* does not?

Second, there is a solution to your problem in a generic way. There is a genuine problem with following omnipresent code:

```
void foo(const std::string& data);
```

It allows using foo with both std::strings and const char*, and suits almost everybody. It does not matter for majority of users of foo(), but for someone really fixed on performance (as in nanoseconds) creation of temporary std::string from their const char* is a sore point. To solve this problem, StringRef was invented. It is not available in std, but it exits in many libraries including boost, and is simple to implement. The idea is following:

```
class StringRef {
    ...
    StringRef(const std::string& str) : b(str.begin()), end(str.end()) {}
    StringRef(const char* str) : b(str), end(str + strlen(str)) {}
    ...
    private:
    const char* const b;
    const char* const e;
};

void foo(const StringRef str);
```

Comment: I'm not against `StringRef`, but for this particular case of "optimizing" the creation of an object representing an empty string, it's not at all clear to me that it does a significantly better job than `std::string` with a small string optimization. Fewer conditions evaluated, probably.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I was using this as an opportunity to promote StringRef, which doesn't get love it deserves (not even made it's way into std). Of course, for an empty string creation it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 4):

There's no (safe) way of making a reference refer to nothing. If you don't want an object to be created at all, you have to use a pointer;

```
int process(const std::string *s = nullptr);
```

If you want to use references, there must be an object somewhere. For that purpose, you could use a default-constructed (empty) string as default argument;

```
int process(const std::string& s = std::string());
```

Comment: You can use a pointer, not have to. There are other alternatives `boost::optional` for example.

Comment: I know boost::optional. I'm coming from C, Java and PHP and trying to minimize pointer usage...

Comment: In recent compilers there is also std::experimental::optional, which might make it into C++17; `int process(std::experimental::optional<std::string> s = std::experimental::nullopt)`, although that means you're always passing by value. Also, don't be afraid to use pointers when it's right to do so.